# Nodejs and Express, use res.send() from a worker thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, worker-thread

In Nodejs, using Express as a server, I offload a heavy computation onto a worker thread.

From the main application, I call the worker thread like this:

```js
// file: main.js

const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");

function runService(fileName, workerData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const worker = new Worker(fileName, { workerData });
        worker.on("message", resolve);
        worker.on("error", reject);
        worker.on("exit", code => {
            if (code !== 0)
                reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
        });
    });
}

router.get("/some_url", async function(req, res) {
    const result = await runService(
        "./path/to/worker.js",
        { query: req.query, user: req.user } // using { req } causes an error
    );
});
```

The worker looks like this:

```js
// file: worker.js

const { workerData, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
const { query, user } = workerData;

async function run() {
    const result = await generateLotsOfData(query, user);

    parentPort.postMessage(result);

    // What I would like to do here (doesn't work): res.send(result);
}
```

The worker generates a huge amount of data and "postMessage" causes a server error.

Is there a way to send this data from the worker thread directly to the client, using `res.send()` or something alike?
(instead of using `postMessage` and then sending from the main thread)?

Comment: would streams help?

Comment: not sure about your exact usecase, bt you should be able to stream the values using res.write() as shown here: https://gist.github.com/montanaflynn/6a438f0be606daede899

Comment: I would still have to send data from the worker thread to the main thread before I can use res.write(). Streams might still be useful because I would have to send Les data a time.

Comment: Did you find a solution @HendrikJan? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: @lukas1994 I did not find a way to send directly from the worker-thread. See my answer for how I finally resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**This sample of code works :**

1. create worker
2. create event handler
3. sendMessage --> wrapperWorkerThreadBigComputing
4. sendBack message on our main thread
5. emit server response

**Api routes :**

```
app.get('/bigComputingWithWorker', (req, res) => {
     const worker = new Worker(`${__dirname}/src/wrapperWorkerThreadBigComputing.js`);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      worker.once("message", count => {
        res.status(200).send(`The final count :${count}`);
    });
    worker.once("error", err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(400).send(`error worker thread`);
    });
     worker.postMessage({coucou : 'john'});
});
```

wrapperWorkerThreadBigComputing

```
const { parentPort } = require('node:worker_threads');

console.log("* worker created");
parentPort.once('message', (message) => {
      let big = bigComputing();
      parentPort.postMessage(big);
})

function bigComputing() {
    let i = 0;
    console.log("* start big computing")
    for (i = 0; i < 300000000; i++) {
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to send directly from the worker-tread to the client.
In the end, I used child-process (instead of worker-treads), and send the result back to the main tread, and then to the client.

```js
// file: main.js

var child_process = require('child_process');

// Run a worker thread
function runService(fileName, workerData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const worker = child_process.fork(fileName);

        worker.on('message', function(message) {
            if (message.ready) {
                // worker is ready to receive data
                worker.send(workerData);
            } else {
                // worker finished it's calculations, send the data to the client
                resolve(message);
            }
        });

        worker.on("error", function(x) {
            console.log('error', x);
            resolve({status: 500});
        });
        worker.on("close", function(y) {
            console.log('close', y);
        });
        worker.on("exit", function(code) {
            if (code == 0) {
                console.log('report ran successfully');
            } else {
                console.log('report FAILED');
                resolve({status: 500});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And in the worker:

```js
process.on('message', run);
process.send({ready: true});

async function run(workerData) {
    try {
        const result = doSomeCalculations();

        process.send({
            data: JSON.stringify(result)
        }, null, {}, function() {process.exit(0)});
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1); // exit the process with a failure
    }
}

// Make sure that this child_process doesn't accidentally stay in memory.
// Kill after 10 minutes. (not sure this is necessary, just to be sure)
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('Timeout in child-process');
    process.exit(1);
}, 600000);
```

This actually works quite well.